# Optimal perfect matchings in magic squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-matchings

**Question:**

> what is known about minimum/maximum weight perfect matchings in [magic squares](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html) with or without special properties like e.g. being [pandiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandiagonal_magic_square)?

I am especially interested minimal/maximal cell-values that can be covered by e.g. a minimum-weight perfect matching and also in the minimal/maximal weight of perfect matchings as a function of the square's dimension and possibly the special type of the magic square.

**Addendum**

- The Magic squares at which this question is primarily aimed are matrices $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathrm{N}_+^{n\times n}:\ \lbrace a_{ij}\in \boldsymbol{A}\rbrace\ \equiv\ \lbrace 1,\,\dots,\,n^2\rbrace$
  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ij}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ii}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i\,n-i}=\frac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$
- a perfect matching of $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a set of $n$ of its cells $a_{ij}$ such that every row and every column contains exactly one of these cells. Transversal and assignment are synonyms in this context.

Comment: A perfect matching is usually interpreted on a graph; what is the graph that corresponds to a magic square?

Comment: @BillBradley It is a complete bipartite graph with vertex sets $R$ and $C$ labelled with row indices, resp. column indices. To cite [ Tarjan](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-40R1.pdf): *Like many of the assignment algorithms that followed it, the Hungarian
Method operates on the bipartite graph G itself, rather than on some flow
network constructed from G*

Comment: Is it right that you are asking for a transversal of the magic square with minimum or maximum sum of the entries in the squares that are traversed? And you are talking about $n\times n$ squares containing the numbers one through $n^2$? For $n=3$, the minimum would be six, and the maximum, $24$, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson 'yes' for all points, but I didn't want to close the door for sets of more 'exotic' magic squares, say, of prime numbers, with equal $n$ and element sum.
I will eventually edit my question accordingly